# Is there a way to nest (or escape) ASP.NET inline code inside HTML angle brackets?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, syntax, inline-code

is it possible to do something like the following in ASP.NET:

```
<tr<%= index++ % 2 == 0 ? " class=\"alt-row\"" : ""; %>>
```

in other words, is there a way to escape the angle brackets for the inline code block or something?

(i know the alternative is:

```
<% if (index++ % 2 == 0) { %>
    <tr class="alt-row">
<% } else { %>
    <tr>
<% } %>
```

.  i'm just curious if the other way is possible)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, your first line of code looks fine.

Comment: Use the alternative - it is MUCH easier to read!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this (at least, in MVC), though your example has a couple errors.

Here's a fixed version:

```
<tr<%= index++ % 2 == 0 ? " class=\"alt-row\"" : "" %>>
```

Comment: ok, this worked.  i was trying to avoid the space for the ones that don't have the class.

Comment: The second error, BTW, was the extra semicolon at the end, which can't be used with %=

Comment: the semi-colon fixed everything actually!  what you have now is what i had except for w/ the semi-colon.  i just put my original back in, removed the semi-colon, and it worked!  thx!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it yet?  A similar test worked just fine for me.

Comment: yes, i have and it hasn't worked for me.  you just exactly what i did??

Comment: Could it just be the missing space between the tr and the <%? Can you post the resulting HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the <% %> construct inside tags to assign properties so I would imagine this would work. Did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <tr class="<%= index++ % 2 == 0 ? "alt-row" : "" %>">
```